# problem api-- Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular

i get this api "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees"
then i tried to use it with *ngFor but this problem happens
"ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  
  employes;
  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { 
    this.http.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees').subscribe(employ =>
{this.employes = employ})
  }
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Salary</th>
        <th scope="col">Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor='let empo of employes ; let i = index '>
        <th scope="row">{{i + 1}}</th>
        <td>{{empo.employee_name}}</td>
        <td>{{empo.employee_salary}}</td>
        <td>{{empo.employee_age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: There may be a few issues here;
1. You do not initiate 'employes' as an array, therefore it will be 'undefined' to begin with.
2. Have you verified that the response to the api call actually returns an 'employes' array? i.e. does 'employ' actually return an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response looks like this:

`{ status: string, data: [], message: string }`

**so you have two options:**

in constructor
`{this.employes = employ.data}`

or

in template view
`<tr *ngFor='let empo of employes.data ; let i = index '>`

---

one of these must work if API response successful

And you better move your http request into OnInit method,
so you component should look like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

 employes;

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.http.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
   .subscribe(res => this.employes = res.data);
 }
}
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:12:61 - error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'.
    
    12     empServices.get().subscribe(act=> this.Activities = act.data);

this message appears in the terminal what it is ??
the main problem solved but this message appears